# Unit of (Lagrangian) Floer cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, symplectic-geometry, morse-theory

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and $L \subseteq M$ be a compact Lagrangian in M. My question is what is a geometric/natural representative for the unit of the Floer cohomology $HF(L,L)$? Or what is a naive reason why one can expect that the Floer cohomology is unital in good cases?

I know that there is technicality about when one can use what as the
coefficient ring but let's just assume $(M,\omega)$ and $L$ satisfy reasonable assumptions and come with an extra structure, a perturbation, etc.. From my understanding, the Floer cochain complexes
is freely generated by points in the intersection $L \cap \phi^1(L)$ where 
$\phi^1$ is a time-$1$ Hamiltonian isotopy. The product structure 
$$\mu^2 : CF(L,\phi^1(L) ) \otimes CF(\phi^1(L),\phi^2(L)) \rightarrow
CF(L, \phi^2(L))$$
is given by counting $\deg 0$ pseudo-holomorphic discs having three
marketed points with conditions correspond to the points.

My question is how can one expect this definition produce a unital
ring and how can one know which points should give the unit? Any reference
or answers with any assumption are welcome.

Comment: The product $\mu^2$ is given by counting holomorphic triangles; the differential $\mu^1$ is given by counting holomorphic strips. So you expect the unit $\mu^0$ to arise from counting 'holomorphic caps' (a name I just invented for once-punctured discs). The relationships between these on the chain level should (always) arise from counting the ends of the space of holomorphic curves in the Gromov compactification. I am not familiar enough with the details to make this precise, but I would have guessed there's a discussion of units in Seidel's book.